# Dealing with an array of input text dynamically generated in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I want to get the phone numbers of the customer in a form that generates the input text dynamically. I have made this

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> get telephones </TITLE>

<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function add(type) {

//Create an input text dynamically.

    if(typeof add.counter=='undefined')
    {
        add.counter=0;
    }
    add.counter++;
    var element = document.createElement("input");

    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", type);
    element.setAttribute("value", "");
    element.setAttribute("name", type.concat(add.counter));

    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
    return add.counter;

  }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM action="test1.php" method="post">
 //here I think there is a problem
<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="<?php echo "add('text')";?>"/>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Add" />
<span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to get an array of the names of the input text, or the last value of the counter

Answer (score 0):

if you set input name to "whatever[]" then PHP will automatically create array from input data so all you need here is to change

```
element.setAttribute("name", type.concat(add.counter));
// to
element.setAttribute("name", "thename[]");
```

and you don't really want to reuse type of elements for it's name - that's 2 very different things, come up with something better

and drop all that counter stuff

Comment: i gave you more than enough **details**. without details my answer would look like "append [] to name of your inputs and you will get an array when you post your form data"

Answer (score 0):

Here Answer

```
  <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add('text')"/>
 <INPUT type="button" value="allPhoneNumbers" onclick="allPhoneNumbers()"/>
<script type="javascript">
  function add(type) 
  {
  if(typeof add.counter=='undefined')
 {
    add.counter=0;
 }
 add.counter++;
 var element = document.createElement("input");

 //Assign different attributes to the element.
 element.setAttribute("type", type);
 element.setAttribute("value", "");
 element.setAttribute("id", type.concat(add.counter));
 element.setAttribute("name", 'phonenumbers[]');

 var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

 //Append the element in page (in span).
 foo.appendChild(element);
 return add.counter;
}
 function allPhoneNumbers()
 {
var phonenumbers=document.getElementsByName('phonenumbers[]');

    for(var i=0;i<phonenumbers.length;i++)
    {
        alert(phonenumbers[i].value);
    }     }

</script>
```

Comment: thanks, and how to get their values using php?can I use the $_post['phonenumbers[i]']

Comment: After Form Submition u can get Like this in php               <?php                           $phonenumbers=$_POST['phonenumbers'];
         $size=sizeOf($phonenumbers);
         for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)
          {
    echo $phonenumbers[$i];
          }                                                        ?>